# How to remove a specific face after using solidify

Tags: modeling, solidify-modifier

I'm trying to create a shelve. I've gone as far as:

- Creating a plane
- Divide it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> in 4
- Select all faces in the middle and remove them
- Select all vertices and extract them by 30cm
- Use the *Solidify* modifier to add some thickness to the shelf

[image]

While this would be ok for a basic shelve, I want one slightly more complicated where there's a part on the side that is only half of the full size, like this (where the red cross should be no face):

[image]

I'm struggling here because of this:

[image]

Here the *Solidify* made it as a triangle shape, meaning if I want to remove all the panel, I need to remove the 2 sides and one is longer than the other:

[image]

How can I manage to build what I want? Is there a trick with the modifier? I thought about adding an extra cut and put it close to existing point so I could remove the face without trouble but the extra cut shows like this:

[image]

Which isn't helping.

Is there maybe a better way from the start to make that shelf?

On top of that, I'm guessing there's an issue with the normals because when I apply a material onto it, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: To add to Vagabonk's solution, don't use the Solidify for the shelves, it won't give you a good topology

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now that I've read his answer! I tried to think it differently many times with extrude too but couldn't get it right. I tried to basically built it with extruding but from the front face, instead of the bottom and it didn't work out at all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm getting the shape right, based on your diagram, but:

1. Create a plane and extrude. E > 0.05 m in my case. This is going to be the thickness of the shelf.
2. Create two loop cuts CRTL+R in the middle, and use S > Y (or X if you are using the other axis) to fit the loop evenly in both edges (you can also use the numpad).
   [image]
3. Create another loop cut in the middle (the other one), exit edit mode and duplicate the item two times with SHIFT+D.
   [image]
4. Select these three faces and extrude the needed height (I used 0.4 m)
   [image]
5. Do the same for the other side:
   [image]
6. Select the right side (that will be the bottom) and create and array modifier:[image]
7. Do the same for the other side, but first move it one unit up, which would be the height of the shelf (0.45 m in my case):
   [image]
8. Put the top using the snap tool:
   [image]
9. Here you can apply the Array Modifiers, then join (CRTL+J) and merge by distance (M, in edit mode) if needed.